# regexp to find image path file in an image tag

Tags: php, image

I'm looking for a regexp that find **all images path** in an image tag (src) and transform **all images path** by cid:filename

```
<img src="../images/text.jpg" alt="test" />
```

to

```
<img src="cid:test" alt="test" />
```

Thanks for your help

Chris

Comment: Just to clarify this: src="../images/text.jpg" should be src="../images/test.jpg" or do you really want to insert the value of the alt attribute as cid?

Answer (score 2):

As Web Logic suggested, I would rather give the PHP DOM Extension a try, especially if you are working with a whole HTML document. You can either pass some HTML fragment to an instance of PHP DOM or the contents of a complete HTML page.

One example of how to do what you suggest if you just have a string of an image element like `<img src="../images/text.jpg" alt="test" />` and want to set the `src` attribute of it to the image-filename without the file extension prefixed by `cid:`

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Load one or more img elements or a whole html document from string
$doc->loadHTML('<img src="../images/text.jpg" alt="test" />'); 

// Find all images in the loaded document
$imageElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
// Temp array for storing the html of the images after its src attribute changed
$imageElementsWithReplacedSrc = array();

// Iterate over the found elements
foreach($imageElements as $imageElement) {
  // Temp var, storing the value of the src attribute
  $imageSrc = $imageElement->getAttribute('src');
  // Temp var, storing the filename with extension
  $filename = basename($imageSrc);
  // Temp var, storing the filename WITHOUT extension
  $filenameWithoutExtension = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')); 
  // Set the new value of the src attribute
  $imageElement->setAttribute('src', 'cid:' . $filenameWithoutExtension);

  // Save the html of the image element in an array
  $imageElementsWithReplacedSrc[] = $doc->saveXML($imageElement);
}

// Dump the contents of the array
print_r($imageElementsWithReplacedSrc);
```

Prints this result (using PHP 5.2.x on Windows Vista):

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="cid:text" alt="test"/>
)
```

---

If you want to set the value of the `src` attribute to the value of the alt attribute prefixed by `cid:`, look at this:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Load one or more img elements or a whole html document from string
$doc->loadHTML('<img src="../images/text.jpg" alt="test" />');

// Find all images in the loaded document
$imageElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
// Temp array for storing the html of the images after its src attribute changed
$imageElementsWithReplacedSrc = array();

// Iterate over the found elements
foreach($imageElements as $imageElement) {
  // Set the new value of the src attribute
  $imageElement->setAttribute('src', 'cid:' . $imageElement->getAttribute('alt'));

  // Save the html of the image element in an array
  $imageElementsWithReplacedSrc[] = $doc->saveXML($imageElement);
}

// Dump the contents of the array
print_r($imageElementsWithReplacedSrc);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="cid:test" alt="test"/>
)
```

I hope that gets you started. These are only examples of what to do with the DOM extension, your description of what you need to parse (HTML fragments or complete HTML document) and what you need to output/store were a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the **[PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)** to parse your html and do the search replace accordingly.

Otherwise, you can also use the **[JQuery](http://jquery.org)** for that to do the stuff easily:

```
$(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src').replace('cid:' + $(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but do you have any idea for a PHP regexp ?

Comment: @Chris: You can use the `preg_replace` function for that but i think there is no need for regex there.

Comment: Well I need a regexp because it will be a template to be use for a newsletter